# how to make edit link in display form in my php form?

Tags: php, html

I am very new to PHP. I have a PHP page to enter data and displaying data. The page takes data and displays data. But edit link to edit a specific row is not working. It gives an error **object not found**. I  am trying to fix it but no clue. Any help will be appreciated.

```
echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["name"]."</td><td><a href=\"".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."/" . $row["id"] . "\"><i class=\"fa fa-edit\"> </i> Edit</a></td></tr>";
```

Comment: Please also add the codes so that we can review it properly

Comment: echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["name"]."</td><td><a href=\"".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."/" . $row["id"] . "\"><i class=\"fa fa-edit\"> </i> Edit</a></td></tr>";

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<?php
$link = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td>
     <td>".$row["name"]."</td>
     <td><a href='$link' ". $row["id"] . "><i class=\"fa fa-edit\"> </i> Edit</a></td>
     </tr>";
     ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Aroon. I have tried your solution but it doesn't take me anywhere to edit. Stays on the same page or just refresh the page.

Comment: where do you want to redirect? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; means same page navigation

Comment: Yes! on the same page,the page has entry form and display table. When I click on "Edit" it should stay on the same page and display table remain same. But entry form should be fill with data where id=$row['id']